# Подгрузка данных в RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, recyclerview

Реализовал приложение которое грузит статьи с сайта. Статей 400+ через `JSON` гружу последние 10. Остальные планирую грузить другим отдельным таском по запросу пользователя.
Вопрос:
Как прикрутить кнопку в низу `RecyclerView`, что бы можно было при желании подгрузить следующие 10 статей. Или может что то другое посоветуете?

Comment: Могу показать как реализовать подгрузку новых элементов когда пользователь дошёл до конца списка)

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Создать и прикрутить кнопку, или сделать запрос к серверу по нажатию на эту кнопку, или вставить полученные данные?

Comment: Почему не добавить кастомный item "Load More" последним в списке, при нажатии на который он будет подменяться (ну или просто скрывать на нем текст и показывать крутилку) другим с лоадером?

Comment: а по автомитической подгрузке опять же анализировать текущий контент оффсет и общий, когда значение больше определнного - обновлять

Comment: Это адаптер с несколькими типами вьюх. Смотреть на [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish не откажусь.)

Comment: @Regent прикрутить саму кнопку, с логикой загрузки данных все ок.

Comment: @lsillarionov попробуем.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для автоматической подгрузки, если пользователь прокрутил список до конца, вам нужно использовать кастомный `OnScrollListener`

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();//смотрим сколько элементов на экране
            int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();//сколько всего элементов
            int firstVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();//какая позиция первого элемента

            if (!isLoading) {//проверяем, грузим мы что-то или нет, эта переменная должна быть вне класса  OnScrollListener 
                if ( (visibleItemCount+firstVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    isLoading = true;//ставим флаг что мы попросили еще элемены
                    if(loadingListener != null){
                        loadingListener.loadMoreItems(totalItemCount);//тут я использовал калбэк который просто говорит наружу что нужно еще элементов и с какой позиции начинать загрузку
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Не забываем назначить его `_recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);`

Есть небольшая особенность, этот код не будет работать с `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Грузите следующую партию статей и добавляете в адаптер, после добавления вызываете у адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()` и ставите флаг `isLoading = false`

В адаптере вам нужно сделать что бы его размер был (реальный размер + 1) и отображать последний элемент как индикатор загрузки.

Comment: как то не удалось.

Comment: ну думаю это проблема интеграции, я это не из головы брал)

Comment: Засчитано как ответ. Сама подгрузка получилась при прокрутке до конца списка. Но не все гладко. Адаптер что то не хочет обновляться получая новый список статей. Но будет копать дальше. Спасибо.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() нужно вызывать в главном потоке, проблема распостраненная

Comment: Та я в курсе, использую, просто там у меня идет сохранение в БД, а потом уже вывод с него. И наткнулся на такую проблему: прокрутил в низ, таском загрузило следующие 10 записей, и почему то только они отображаются, если перезайти в приложение то отображается все 20. Я пока что не опытен первое приложение) Походу логику отображения после загрузки нужно ковырять.)

Comment: Скорее логику выборки из базы после добавления новых записей) при обновлении списка вам нужно добиться что бы выборка отработала так же как и при первой инициализации, если вы говорите что при перезапуске все правильно отображается

Comment: Ну я об этом и хотел сказать)

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish а что такое isLoading?
Что это за переменная?

И хотелось бы узнать что находится в коллбэке?

Comment: это просто булевая переменная, там же написано.

Answer (score 2):

Ловить момент, когда следует подгружать данные, можно двумя способами:

1) Как и писал SorryForMyEnglish, повесить на `RecyclerView` слушатель прокрутки и, когда он будет прокручен до последнего элемента, подгружать новую порцию данных. Вот пример реализации такого способа: https://github.com/ziginsider/DynamicLoadingRecyclerView

2) В адаптере можно получить позицию только что появившегося элемента списка. Если позиция появившегося элемента последняя, значит пора подгружать новую порцию данных:

```
  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    int layoutPosition = holder.getLayoutPosition();
    // тут проверяем не последний ли элемент и запускаем калбэк
    // аналогично первому способу
  }
```

Comment: Что за `getLayoutPosition`? Может, `getAdapterPosition`?

Comment: Нет, я не ошибся. В большинстве ситуаций методы вернут одинаковый результат. Но в getAdapterPosition() можно получить NO_POSITION. Дело в том, что в момент вызова getAdapterPosition() ViewHolder может находиться в состоянии dirty или scrap ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html ) и поэтому мы рискуем получить непредсказуемый результат. В то время как getLayoutPosition ( developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition() ) всегда возвращает позицию, даже если идет обновление.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что в случае нетривиальных LayoutManager (StaggeredGrid etc.). Я бы не полагался и на getLayoutPosition() т.к. в этих случаях позиция во ViewHoldera во вьюхе может не совпадать с его позицией в адаптере.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вообще ловить это дело в `onBindViewHolder`

Но сначала интерфейс создайте в адаптере

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}
```

Переменную

```
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
```

Ну и сеттер для неё

```
public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener listener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = listener;
}
```

Теперь создадим в адаптере переменные `isLoading` и `noMore`. Первая нужна будет для того, чтобы избежать бага "почему айтемы копируются", а вторая чтобы избежать `почему он вечно крутится".

```
private boolean isLoading, noMore;
```

Сеттеры для них

```
public void endLoading() {
    this.isLoading = false;
}

public void setNoMore(boolean noMore) {
    this.noMore = noMore;
}
```

Теперь в `onBindViewHolder` можно написать так:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(...) {
    //ваш биндинг

    if(onLoadMoreListener != null && !isLoading && !noMore && holder.getAdapterPosition() == getItemCount() - 1) {
        isLoading = true;
        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
    }
}
```

В активности вешаем на адаптер созданный слушатель и в `onLoadMore` пишем подгрузку, добавляем то что погрузили в общую коллекцию и обновляем список

```
recyclerViewAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore() {
        List<Book> newBooks = //допустим книги и допустим вы их подгрузили 
        totalBooks.addAll(newBooks); //totalBooks это коллекция книг которая содержит все данные для списка
        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerViewAdapter.endLoading(); //когда загрузка завершена
        recyclerViewAdapter.setNoMore(true); //если подгружать больше нечего
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное можно и так, но, думаю, это не самый лучший путь. Во-первых, странно ловить позицию в `onBindViewHolder` через `getAdapterPosition()`, когда мы получаем `position`, как параметр `onBindViewHolder`. Я не говорю, что это не правильно. Но должно насторожить. Во-вторых, как известно, `onBindViewHolder` не вызывается при смене элементом своей позиции. Поэтому, в некоторых случаях, ваш подход может не работать.

Comment: Я уже всегда использую для списков либу от BRVAH - RecyclerViewHelper. Там loadMore есть из коробки

Comment: +1 Кстати, вполне себе нормальный способ решения проблемы подгрузки - использовать готовое решение. Единственное, что придется тянуть в проект всю библиотеку, это не всегда может подойти.

Comment: Вы не судите меня :) Я просто работаю и некогда писать то, что уже написано. Этим принципом работает вся команда. В нашем проекте куча списков и, вы не поверите, эта библиотека покрывает все наши нужды, она очень удобная для любых списков. Поэтому так :) Я очень хочу посмотреть исходный код этой библиотеки, но нет времени :(

Comment: Многие библиотеки, например, помогают делать привычные вещи быстрее, а что-то особенное 100% писать надо самому. Кстати, у нас 3 библиотеки все нужды даже не покрывают и приходится добавлять их модулем и в них разбираться, добавлять функционал