# Как сделать подгружаемый RecyclerView?

Tags: recyclerview, android

Как сделать подгружаемый RecyclerView как в Instagram? Чтобы при достижении конца списка загружалась другая порция данных.

Comment: http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подгрузки следующего списка данных, (если пользователь прокрутил список до конца) вам нужно использовать кастомный `OnScrollListener`для `recyclerview`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430688