# Прокрутка RecyclerView с последующим добавлением элементов

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Парсю новости с одного новостного портала, которые в последствии отображаются в моем `RecyclerView`. Я не включаю в свой список рекламные новости, поэтому бывает так, что со страницы портала я получаю от 24 до 27 статей. Я хочу сделать, чтобы как только на экране появлялся элемент с позицией `list.size()-2`, приложение начало парсить следующую страницу, добавлять в `RecyclerView` и тд.

Может быть у кого есть готовый кусок кода по моему вопросу? Буду весьма признателен!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430688/14141

Comment: Не совсем ответ, но может вам будет интересен вариант "как организовать логику загрузки данных из сети и размещения их в `RecyclerView`" представленный недавно на [одном докладе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5afEeuI0GQ). Сам код [здесь](https://gitlab.com/terrakok/gitlab-client/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/ru/terrakok/gitlabclient/presentation/global/Paginator.kt).

Answer (score 1):

у ресайклера есть OnScrollListener. Собственно вам надо написать свою реализацию. Как это сделать - лучше почитать описания методов получения кол-ва элементов списка в документации ресайклера.

Погуглив нашел вот такой пример [на гитхабе](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, спасибо ребята! Собрал инфу с источников, реализовал простенькую обработку прокрутки таким образом:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if(dy>0){
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) newsList.getLayoutManager();
                    int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    Log.d("logs", "lastVisibleItemPosition-"+lastVisibleItemPosition);
                    if (lastVisibleItemPosition > list.size()-2){ // ArrayList<NewsModel> list;
                        numberPage++; //номер страницы откуда нужно парсить, перваоначальное значение было 1.
                        parseAndSaveNews(numberPage); //парсинг и сохранение новостей со следующей страницы
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас понял вам нужна бесконечная прокрутка для `RecyclerView`. Для таких целей можно использовать `EndlessScrollListener`(или взять за основу). Примеры и подробности можно найти  [здесь](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView).